# C programming: reading from file

Tags: c, file-io, text-files

I have customer data such as customer no, the coordinates of location etc. And there are 25 customers in the text file.

Here's my code. This gives me an output of zeros when I print it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define customerCount 25


struct customerData
{
       int customerNo;
       double xCoordinate;
       double yCoordinate;
       double demand;
       double readyTime;
       double dueTime;
       double serviceTime;
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    struct customerData allSubscriber[customerCount];
    FILE *dosya;
    dosya = fopen("c:\\solomon_c101.txt", "r");

        for(i=1; i<=customerCount; i++)
        {
                fscanf(dosya, "%d %f %f %f %f %f %f", &allSubscriber[i].customerNo, &allSubscriber[i].xCoordinate, &allSubscriber[i].yCoordinate, &allSubscriber[i].demand, &allSubscriber[i].readyTime, &allSubscriber[i].dueTime, &allSubscriber[i].serviceTime);
        }
        fclose(dosya);

    for(i=1; i<=customerCount; i++)
    {
             printf("%f\n", &allSubscriber[i].xCoordinate);
    }


    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `conio.h`,it's not standard C and may not work in all environments.

Comment: You want to be using `%lf` with `fscanf()`, not `%f`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
printf("%f\n", allSubscriber[i].xCoordinate);
```

instead of

```
printf("%f\n", &allSubscriber[i].xCoordinate);
```

As another user pointed out,use `%lf` as the format specifier for `double` in `fscanf()`.In printf() it gets promoted to double.

Don't use `conio.h` and `getch()`.Those are not standard C.

Comment: `%lf` is needed only for `scanf()`. For `printf()` `%f` prints `double` (`float` gets promoted to `double` when passed as a vararg).

Comment: Thanks but when I try this, it gives me irrelevant numbers in the output. And I used getch() for stop closing the console window. It is ok if I delete conio.h and getch() and use getchar()?

Comment: @BurcuGül So what alterations you made to the code my Turkish friend?Please tell what you changed in the code.Else show the edits in your question.

Comment: I changed the &f with &lf in scanf and deleted & in printf. But now it prints numbers that are not relevant with my data.

Comment: @BurcuGül Include some code in your program that detects and displays a message if there is error reading from the file `solomon_c101.txt`.I just ran your code.It compiled well,but program crashed.I realized I don't have any such file on my c drive!!!

Comment: @BurcuGül The data in your file `solomon_c101.txt` must be in the format you have specified in your `fscanf()`.Else using this program to read that will certainly produce weird output.I used to store custom-data as `employee-records` in a `dat` file and I used to read from it using `fscanf()`.I ran your program.It compiles fine.Don't worry,you've got your logic right.It seems you've obtained this program from somewhere.First try your own simple programs for `fscanf()`.Else I'll post you my own program and custom-made data file.

Comment: @BurcuGül Do use this snippet after the `dosya = fopen("c:\\solomon_c101.txt", "r");` statement.It ensures that you know when there is a read error from the file-- `if(dosya==NULL){printf("Error opening File"); exit(1);}`

Comment: Ok, now it says there is an error in opening file but I have solomon_c101.txt file in C. So I guess the data in the file causes the error. I will try to correct it, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

use the `%lf` to read a `double` in `scanf`

`printf("%f\n", &allSubscriber[i].xCoordinate);` //remove `&`